# Passing a string literal as Javascript .replace() pattern with global flag

Tags: javascript, regex, loops, syntax, replace

I have the following that is iterating over an array of "templateOverrides".  `DPGlobal.template` is the original template which I need to override.  My issue is that I need to pass the `g` flag to the `.replace()` method on the `var newTemplate = ...` line.  It's working insofar as I am able to dynamically iterate through and override template pieces one at a time, but the `g` flag is not passed.  I'm mainly curious what is the most DRY method of achieving it...

```
for ( var i in templateOverrides ) {
    var thisOverride = templateOverrides[i];
    var origGlobalTemplate = DPGlobal[thisOverride];
    var newTemplate = DPGlobal.template.replace(origGlobalTemplate, options[thisOverride]);
    DPGlobal.template = newTemplate;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare it via [`new RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), you can then include the `/g` modifier as the second parameter to the constructor

```
var newTemplate = DPGlobal.template.replace(new RegExp(origGlobalTemplate,'g'), options[thisOverride]);
```

By the way, is `templateOverrides` *really* an `Array []`, or is it an object `{}`? If it is an `Array`, you ought to be using an incremental for loop rather the `for-in` construct, whose purpose is iterating over object properties.

```
for ( var i=0; i<templateOverrides.length; i++ ) {
  var thisOverride = templateOverrides[i];
  var origGlobalTemplate = DPGlobal[thisOverride];
  var newTemplate = DPGlobal.template.replace(new RegExp(origGlobalTemplate,'g'), options[thisOverride]);
  DPGlobal.template = newTemplate;
}
```

Comment: It is *really* an array - in which case I appreciate your help on that count as well - thanks so much!

Comment: @Brian [Here's a great explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays) of the difference between iteration methods and potential consequences...